# Logback RollingFileAppender not working in concurrent writing to same log?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

We have a desktop application and recently introduce logback to the system.All the logs are going to the same place.And it's rolling nicely for single client.But if we run two client of the same application log file not rolling even after it's exceed its limit.If one client close rolling happens nicely.

```
<appender name="LOG-FILE"
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>\log\log.txt</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>\log\old\log.%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>100KB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
    <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} > [%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</Pattern>
</layout>
```

Comment: I would guess that RollingFileAppender is just not prepared for sharing log files between two JVMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default writing from multiple applications to the same file is supported (it might work for you, but you can see unexpected behavior when they both try to write at the same time).

You can solve this by enable [prudent mode](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent) for your appender. This is done by setting `prudent="true"` as an attribute of your `<appender>` tag.

Note that for `RollingFileAppender` [extra restrictions](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling) apply. For you this means you can not specify the 'file' property. Also you can not use the `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP` but you have to change to a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`.

Comment: This answer is helpful. I think windows operating system does not allow renaming of a file while another process has it opened.SO problem is there but nothing to do.We need SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP to use.Thanks.

Comment: @Prabhath If you need that, then I don't think you have many options. Do note that the `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP ` is only useful for splitting up files in smaller chunks. Your configuration will not limit the filesize of your total logging. Instead it will save 2 days of logging in chunks of at most 100 KB (which is a misinterpretation I made when using it for the first time).